# How to I set a ruby variable based on an if-then decision tree

Tags: ruby, syntax

I want to write the following:

```
variable = if x
  a
else
  if y
    b
  else
    c
  end
end
```

Where if x is true, variable equals a.  If x is false and y is true, variable equals b.  If x and y are both false, variable equals c.

I thought this was valid ruby syntax but when I try it, the variable is always set to nil.  Why is this and how do I set it correctly?

I am using ruby 1.9.3 btw

Edit: FALSE ALARM.  In my example, c was set to nil which I thought was erroneous.  My original syntax worked fine.  I'm not sure of the StackOverflow etiquette on whether I should delete this question, advise is welcome.

Thanks for the quick responses.

Comment: Once answer will be having votes, you can't delete this.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not make it complicated! There is nothing wrong with writing

```
variable = 
  if    x then a
  elsif y then b
  else  c
end
```

No one will look at this code and not figure out what has happend.

Comment: Might try that for clarity.  As it turns out, my original way worked as well though

Comment: This will good, if code block has only single statement.. for multiline block code, nope not a good choice.

Comment: Well, of course if you need to insert longer code you can skip the `then` keyword and use a new line and indent instead, but otherwise there is no difference between a nested if statement and an elsif.

Answer (score 1):

There two main variants:

1. With a `if-else-end` tree:

   ```
   variable =
   if x
     a
   else
     if y
       b
     else
       c
     end
   end
   ```
2. and as a logical boolean algebra expression:

   ```
   variable = x && a || ( y && b || c )
   ```

   That is the same as:

   ```
   variable = x && a || y && b || c
   ```

The first variant is usually preferred, then you are using complex code or calculation inside the `if-else-end` blocks. The second, when the simple read/logical constructions is used.

If you have an error or get an invalid result in your expression, just check your logical expression.

Comment: Thanks, your first variant is nearly identical to mine.  It turns out both work.

Comment: +1 for mentioning *The first variant is usually preferred, then you are using complex code or calculation inside the if-else-end blocks.*